# Compiling third party libraries with Qt

Tags: qt, opencv, marble

I've been using OpenCV and Marble libraries compiled and linked with Qt. Every time I do it I have problems running cmake to make these libraries. it seems paths in the qt cmake files to other qt cmake files are incorrect. I get errors like:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:67 (find_package):
By not providing "FindQt5DBus.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5DBus", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5DBus" with any
of the following names:

Qt5DBusConfig.cmake
qt5dbus-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5DBus" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Qt5DBus_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"Qt5DBus" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.
```

I can fix this in Ubuntu by running

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

This is fine in Ubuntu, but now I am trying to compile these libraries on mac and windows now. Anyone know a way to get a Qt with all of these paths already correct? tried the installer on windows and mac, and brew on mac. I don't really have time to play with fixing each one of these errors one by one

Answer (score 0):

At least Qt 5.5 on Windows (using the Qt installer) should work out of the box. It has DBus included. Which Qt version are you using currently?